# How do I encrypt with the private key?

Tags: encryption, public-key, signature

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [RSA encryption with private key and decryption with a public key](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/2123/rsa-encryption-with-private-key-and-decryption-with-a-public-key)

This wording is creeping everywhere ([e.g. there](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/4020)): "I encrypt with the private key" and even sometimes, "I decrypt with the public key." Does it make any sense?